# How do I divide elements in a single column of a python dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, division

I need to divide every element in a specific column in a Pandas DataFrame by 100.

By default, the .div() function in Pandas divides *all* elements across all columns, and attempting to specify columns to divide leaves me with only those columns.

```py
d = {
    'SYMBOL':['AAAAA','BBBBB','CCCCC'],
    'ASSETS':[5, 21, 74]}

data = pd.DataFrame(d,columns=['SYMBOL','ASSETS'])

data = data['ASSETS'].div(100)
```

**So, starting with**

```
    0     AAAAA 5
    1     BBBBB 21
    2     CCCCC 74
```

**I end up getting**

```
    0     0.05
    1     0.21
    2     0.74
```

**When I want**

```
    0     AAAAA 0.05
    1     BBBBB 0.21
    2     CCCCC 0.74
```

Comment: So `data['ASSETS'] /= 100`?

Comment: `data=data.assign(ASSETS=data['ASSETS'].div(100))` you're assigning the entire df with the result instead od just a column

Comment: try `data['ASSETS'] = data['ASSETS'].div(100)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
data['ASSETS'] = data['ASSETS'].div(100)
```

You are overwriting your entire dataframe by assigning it back to data

Answer (score 2):

You can move symbols into the index of the dataframe, with `set_index` then, divide, and lastly `reset_index`:

```
d = {
    'SYMBOL':['AAAAA','BBBBB','CCCCC'],
    'ASSETS':[5, 21, 74]}

data = pd.DataFrame(d,columns=['SYMBOL','ASSETS'])

data = data.set_index('SYMBOL')

data = data.div(100)

print(data.reset_index())
```

Output:

```
  SYMBOL  ASSETS
0  AAAAA    0.05
1  BBBBB    0.21
2  CCCCC    0.74
```

Comment: A bit of an overkill for a simple operation in one column (did not downvote btw) :)

Comment: Yeah.  I agree it is overkill in this situation, but it does show a concept of moving information into the index so, you can easily do a calculation.